# Embed an external application into a Winform for a WinCE platform

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-ce

I was wondering if anyone has any ideas on how to embed a windows application (notepad.exe) into a Winform. I have found an example on line for a desktop appl that embeds word into winform (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11819/Integrating-Microsoft-Word-in-your-NET-application) but unsure how I will do this for notepad.exe or any other executable in Win CE platform. Also it uses the interop assemblies which notepad does not have, and coredll.dll is missing some of the menu functions from the user32.dll.

I have also looked at the MS example using active X and and the AxHost library from opennetCF but it uses the exposed functions from the DLL (WMPLib.dll and ShockWaveObjects.dll). I have tried this example and copied the DLL to my windows folder but it crashes with the exception message "Class not registered".

Paul

Comment: There is "word mobile" already installed on ce devices - could you use that instead of notepad ? It's a bit more functional than notepad but nowhere near the functionality of Word on desktop. If you can use this you wouldn't need to embed, just figure out how to open it with your program

Comment: What, exactly, are you after?  A text editing capability in your app, or simply the ability to launch Notepad from your app on a platform that potentially doesn't have it installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could possibly achieve this by running the executable as a different process and then changing the parent window of the process to one within your winform. This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms961506.aspx) to MSDN shows that the WinCE API exposes the SetParent method.

The same code worked for me in a desktop application, so all going well it would work for the mobile platform as well.